How do I stop Gradle from moving my android studio projects to the #GRADLE_LOCAL_JAVA_HOME macro
So, every time I open a file for a new android studio project it works for a second and then says this error and removes everything.
The 'teamcode' project JDK configuration is now set through the #GRADLE_LOCAL_JAVA_HOME macro. This simplifies the JDK configuration experience and makes it more reliable. You can change this in the Gradle JDK settings.
I am a beginner coder please help.
We tried going through the Gradle files and stopping it but that didn't result in anything different happened. We have also tried restarting android studio and it never worked.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
